# appcmd - ftp authorization rules from IIS 6 to IIS7?

Tags: iis, iis-7, iis-6

I've got an FTP site on a server with IIS 6, and I need to set up a second server (this one with IIS 7) to have the same FTP setup.

I've done the following:

```
appcmd list site /config /xml > SomeFile.xml   [on the first server]
appcmd add site /in < SomeFile.xml   [on the second server]
```

... which works out fine.  Only problem: I'm missing my authorization rules, not just for the base FTP site, but all the individual virtual folders as well.

Is there any way to extract the authorization rules from the site (and all its virtual folders) and then inject them into another site?  Or is there a better way of tackling the problem?